# I can't find class DB code error (laravel 4)

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want use class DB in code, my code this file klasa.php in directory helpers
(Ja zamierzam użyć klasy DB w kodzie mój kod to plik klasa.php w katalogu helpers)
File klasa.php

```
   <?php
 //namespace App\Helpers;
   //use ...\Form;
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Quotation;
class SomeClass
  {
public static function SomeMethod()
{
  print "<font color=red>Dobrze</font>";
}

public static function dodaj_staty($ip,$http_user_agent,$co_robil) {
  //$system = $this->system_operacyjny($http_user_agent);
  //$przegla = $this->przegladarka($http_user_agent);
  $system = "tomi";
  $przegla = "tomek";
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO statystyki (aa, bb, cc,fff,gg,iii)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?,?)';
  $data = time();
  $data1 = array($data, $system ,$przegla,$http_user_agent,$co_robil,$ip);
   //on this line return error  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\\Helpers\\SomeClass' not found
  \DB::insert($sql, $data1);






}
```

this function call in file 
(tą funkcje wywołuje plik)

```
    $a = new \App\Helpers\SomeClass();
 $a->dodaj_staty('d','dd','g');
```

you see use these instructions 
(wy widzicie użyłem takich instrukcji)

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use DB;
   use App\Quotation;
```

Comment: Are you sure you got error `App\\Helpers\\SomeClass` and on that specific line? It does not make sense right now. And please, do not use two languages. It looks really strange especially when both of them looks like straight from google translate

Comment: I changed something and now not throws any errors, but not running, while how delete line which contain note DB::insert It is well.

Answer (score 0):

on this application itself is used logon and this use mysql and it works good, maybe because that not use instructions DB::select. I changed instructions DB::insert at $ff = DB::select and not it was any errors, but how printers variable $ff then see error.